# Angularjs nested controller called just one time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new in Angularjs and I have an app, with some "projects", which have a local menu displayed on some pages. *Index.html* contains the main navbar with footer :

```
<body ng-app="ysi-app" ng-controller="MainController">
<div class="page-content">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="sidebar content-box" style="display: block;">
            <ul class="nav">
                <!-- Main menu -->
                <li ng-if="isAuthenticated()"><a href="#/">{{name}}</a></li>
                <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/project">Projects</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="isAuthenticated() && displayProjectMenu == true" ng-include="'views/localMenu.html'" ng-controller="LocalMenuController">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-view></div>
 </div>
```

So I have a nested controller *LocalMenuController* for the local menu and a main controller. The project controller sets the datas :

```
angular.module('ProjectCtrl',[]).controller('ProjectController',function($scope,$location, ProjectService,$route, AuthenticationService, $rootScope){

    $scope.setProjectDatas = function(projectName, projectId){
        ProjectService.setName(projectName);
        $rootScope.projectId = projectId;
    };});
```

I set the id of one project to the *$rootScope* for testing (I have a Service which will do that better) and get it in the *LocalMenuController* :

```
angular.module('LocalMenuCtrl',[]).controller('LocalMenuController', function($scope, ProjectService, $rootScope) {
    $scope.projectId = '';
    $scope.projectId = $rootScope.projectId;
});
```

I display projects in a table and when I clicked on one of it, the function *setProjectDatas(name,id)* is called. The problem is when I clicked on one project, the id of the project is correct and set but when I go previous and clicked on another project, the id is the old id of the project previously clicked. The datas are not updating. I googled my problem but found nothing on it.
I think the *LocalMenuController* is called only one time but not after.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you

**UPDATE**
I've created a Directive which displays the template but it's still not updating the partial view localMenu.
*LocalMenu Directive* :

```
angular.module('LocalMenuCtrl',[]).controller('LocalMenuController', function($scope, ProjectService, $rootScope) {
    console.log('-> LocalMenu controller');
})
    .directive('localMenu', function($rootScope){
        return {
            templateUrl: '/YSI-Dev/public/views/partials/localMenu.html',
            link: function(scope){
                scope.projectId = $rootScope.projectId;
            }
        };
    });
```

A part of *index.html*

```
<div ng-if="isAuthenticated() && displayProjectMenu == true" ng-controller="LocalMenuController">
                <div local-menu></div>
            </div>
```

*Partial view localMenu* :

```
<div class="sidebar content-box" style="display: block;">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#/project/{{projectId}}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i> Backlog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/project/{{projectId}}/members"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> My team </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the **projectId** from the $rootScope and inject it in the `<a href="#/project/{{projectId}}"` but I have some troubles. What's the way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, try using [directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) instead of ng-controller. You can encapsulate your code and template into a unit. You can also try creating a [component](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component). Pass some data to the directive/component and Angular will take care of updating the template and running whatever needs to run within the directive/component. (Given that you used two-way data-bindings)

From the code above, I cannot see what would trigger LocalMenuController to run again.

Comment: I've created a directive but still not working. I've updated my post but is it the right way to do that ?

Comment: Introduce an attribute called projectId to the directive and in your template you can add project-id="projectId", unlikely that you need to use $rootScope for sharing data.